# How to express for loop in summation notation?

Tags: algorithm

How would I express

```
for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    sum +=1;
}
```

in summation notation?

Comment: what do you mean by summation notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would typically look something like:

[image]

As given, this is basically just `sum = n+1;` since you're just adding one on each iteration, so you wouldn't usually express it as a summation. More often you'd have something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    sum += x[i];
}
```

...which would translate to something like:

[image]

Note: I've used indices from 1 to n for the summation notation, because that's what you'd traditionally use in math, even though it doesn't precisely match the limits of the `for` loop you gave. You *could* use limits of 0 and n instead if you really wanted, but this would be fairly unusual. If you really want to do it anyway:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response Jerry.